# Magento 2.1 Ui Component : Hide and show field base on dropdown field

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, uicomponent, fieldsets

I have a dropdown which shows **day's status** ;either **close or open** selectable form a dropdown. If the **status** is **close** , I want to collapse and hide the open and close timings within that particular field set.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<fieldset name="monday_timings">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Monday Timings</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">501</item>
        </item>
    </argument>    
    <field name="monday_status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\Timetable\Source\IsSpecial</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Monday Status</item>    
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">item</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">monday_status</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">19</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            </item>
    </argument>
    </field>        
 <field name="monday_open_time">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">Timepicker</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Start Time</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">date</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">101</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">monday_open_time</item>
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
            <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">hh:mm:ss</item>
            <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
</field> 
 <field name="monday_close_time">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">Timepicker</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">End Time</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">date</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">105</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">monday_close_time</item>
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
            <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">hh:mm:ss</item>
            <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
</field>
<field name="monday_break_time">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">Timepicker</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Break Time</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">date</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">103</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">monday_break_time</item>            
        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
            <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">hh:mm:ss</item>
            <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
</field> 
 <field name="monday_offbreak_time">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">Timepicker</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">End Break</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">date</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">104</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">monday_offbreak_time</item>            
        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
            <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">hh:mm:ss</item>
            <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
</field>
</fieldset>
```

How can this be achieved ,any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default there are no option for this. You can create custom component and template for this. Try following way:

```
<field name="monday_status">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\Timetable\Source\IsSpecial</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">NameSpace_ModuleName/js/form/element/is-special</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">NameSpace_ModuleName/form/element/is-special</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Monday Status</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">item</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">monday_status</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">19</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

**NameSpace/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/is-special.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select'
], function ($, Select) {
    'use strict';

    return Select.extend({
        defaults: {
            customName: '${ $.parentName }.${ $.index }_input'
        },
        /**
         * Change currently selected option
         *
         * @param {String} id
         */
        selectOption: function(id){
            if(($("#"+id).val() == 0)||($("#"+id).val() == undefined)) {
                $('div[data-index="monday_open_time"]').hide();
                $('div[data-index="monday_close_time"]').hide();
                $('div[data-index="monday_break_time"]').hide();
                $('div[data-index="monday_offbreak_time"]').hide();
            } else if($("#"+id).val() == 1) {
                $('div[data-index="monday_open_time"]').show();
                $('div[data-index="monday_close_time"]').show();
                $('div[data-index="monday_break_time"]').show();
                $('div[data-index="monday_offbreak_time"]').show();
            }
        },
    });
});
```

**NameSpace/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/element/is-special.html**

```
<select class="admin__control-select" data-bind="
    event:{ change: selectOption(uid)},
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId
    },
    hasFocus: focused,
    optgroup: options,
    value: value,
    optionsCaption: caption,
    optionsValue: 'value',
    optionsText: 'label'"
/>
```

Clear cache.

Comment: Perfect, great job !

Comment: can you check this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191972/magento-2-1-ui-component-form-field-token-input

Comment: the above question you answered works great, but there is one flaw -take for example two scenarios 1. For the first time when we create a new entry  the select is set to close  it is Ok , it hides the rest of the associated fields. 2. Once we create an entry and save it , next we go to edit the same entry the select is set to Open ,but the underlying fields does not display /visible . To view the hidden fields we have to first switch to close and then when we select it open the fields appear. if the select is set to open by default the underlying hidden fields must be visible .

Comment: On page load by default we get the values in the variable ($("#"+id).val() are undefined and zero. Is there any thing we are missing or how can we modify this shortcoming.

Comment: Is it possible from $fieldset->addField() (in my block instead)?

Comment: It could be done using switcherConfig

Answer (score 7):

It is also possible in UI component with the `<switcherConfig>`. You can refer magento sales rule module form UI component file. I had a same requirement and I did it by using following code.

```
<field name="allow_to_proceed" sortOrder="10" formElement="checkbox">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <dataType>boolean</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Allow Proceed to Checkout</label>
        <dataScope>allow_to_proceed</dataScope>
        <switcherConfig>
            <rules>
                <rule name="0">
                    <value>1</value>
                    <actions>
                        <action name="0">
                            <target>custom_module_rules_form.custom_module_rules_form.actions.skip_other_rules</target>
                            <callback>show</callback>
                        </action>
                        <action name="1">
                            <target>custom_module_rules_form.custom_module_rules_form.actions.remove_discount</target>
                            <callback>show</callback>
                        </action>
                    </actions>
                </rule>
                <rule name="1">
                    <value>0</value>
                    <actions>
                        <action name="0">
                            <target>custom_module_rules_form.custom_module_rules_form.actions.skip_other_rules</target>
                            <callback>hide</callback>
                        </action>
                        <action name="1">
                            <target>custom_module_rules_form.custom_module_rules_form.actions.remove_discount</target>
                            <callback>hide</callback>
                        </action>
                    </actions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </switcherConfig>        
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <checkbox>
            <settings>
                <valueMap>
                    <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                    <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                </valueMap>
                <prefer>toggle</prefer>
            </settings>
        </checkbox>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

Here `<target>` is your `form_datacomponent_name.section_name.field_name` .

Comment: Is it possible from `$fieldset->addField()` (in my block instead)?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do anything extra default ui component give this functionality.

```
<field name="is_enable">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Enable</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">from_general</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">is_enable</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">
                    Here your message/comment go.
                </item>
                <item name="switcherConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="rules" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                            <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_form.vendor_module_form.general.field</item>
                                    <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">show</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                            <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_form.vendor_module_form.general.field</item>
                                    <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">hide</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

You just have to assign your `field`, your form `namespace`, that's it!.

Comment: is it possible to hide an enitire tab using switcher config?

Answer (score 1):

It works almost great. The only problem is that in case you edit item, it doesn't show expected fields because script run too soon.

setTimeout fix the issue:

```
selectOption: function(id){
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(($("#"+id).val() == 0)||($("#"+id).val() == undefined)) {
            $('div[data-index="monday_open_time"]').hide();
            $('div[data-index="monday_close_time"]').hide();
            $('div[data-index="monday_break_time"]').hide();
            $('div[data-index="monday_offbreak_time"]').hide();
        } else if($("#"+id).val() == 1) {
            $('div[data-index="monday_open_time"]').show();
            $('div[data-index="monday_close_time"]').show();
            $('div[data-index="monday_break_time"]').show();
            $('div[data-index="monday_offbreak_time"]').show();
        }
    }, 1);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried Himanshu's answer but it didn't work for me but this one worked:

```
<settings>
   <switcherConfig>
      <rules>
         <rule name="0">
            <value>0</value>
            <actions>
               <action name="0">
                   <target>vendor_module_form.vendor_module_form.general.field</target>
                   <callback>hide</callback>
               </action>
            </actions>
          </rule>
          <rule name="1">
            <value>1</value>
               <actions>
                  <action name="0">
                      <target>vendor_module_form.vendor_module_form.general.field</target>
                     <callback>show</callback>
                  </action>
               </actions>
          </rule>
       </rules>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
   </switcherConfig>
   <validation>
       <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
   </validation>
</settings>
```

Hope that helps anyone!

Comment: is it possible to hide an enitire tab using switcher config?