# Magento 2.1 Ui Component form field Token input

Tags: magento-2.1, product, uicomponent, ui-form, uielement

I want to add tags in an input field , in a similar fashion as it is done in product form to add catageories - which is show in the image below.
[image]

This much task I have achieved by adding field component in the Custom Ui form

```
<field name="parent">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tags</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.parent</item>
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

But this does not meet my requirement. I do not need the drop down and the options - **I just wanted to add the tags in the input field like Tag1, Tag2 ,Tag 3 ...** Can any one guide where we could make the possible changes to achieve this task.

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is **Yes**, everything is possible with ***UI Components*** because it's really flexible as its introductions.

Otherwise, I don't think depending/overriding on default UI element (like you mentioned in the post - `ui-select`) is a good idea. So, in this tutorial, I will create a new UI element for the tags. It could be use not only in product form but the cms page form or whatever depends on the UI forms.

Now let the fun begin!

Firstly, your ui_component form should looks like this

> StackOverflow/Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<field name="parent">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tags</item>
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">StackOverflow_Catalog/js/form/element/tags</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">StackOverflow_Catalog/form/element/tags</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.parent</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Take a note to **formElement**, **component** and **elementTmpl**. It should be a normal input field.

Now, we need to create the view renderer for that UI element

> StackOverflow/Catalog/view/base/web/js/form/element/tags.js

```
/**
 * StackOverflow Catalog.
 *
 * @category  Mage
 *
 * @author    Toan Nguyen <me@nntoan.com>
 * @copyright 2018 Toan Nguyen (https://nntoan.com)
 */
define([
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator'
], function (_, utils, Element, ko, validator) {
    'use strict';

    return Element.extend({
        defaults: {
            list: ([]),
            valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
            listens: {
                'valueArea': 'onUpdateArea'
            }
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.on('value', this.onUpdateArea.bind(this));
            var self = this;
            var list = this.value().split(',');
            _.each(list, function (value, index) {
                if (value.length > 0) {
                    self.list.push(value.trim());
                }
            });

            return this;
        },

        initObservable: function () {
            this._super();
            this.observe(['valueArea']);
            this.observe('list', this.list);
            return this;
        },

        onUpdateArea: function (value) {
            if (value.length > 1) {
                if (value.indexOf(',') !== -1 || value.indexOf(' ') !== -1) {
                    var newValue = value.slice(0, -1);
                    this.correctValue(newValue);
                }
            }
        },

        correctValue: function (tag) {
            if (this.hasTag(tag)) {
                this.valueArea('');
                return false;
            }
            if (this.isValidTag(tag).passed) {
                this.list.push(tag);
                this.joinList(this.list());
                this.valueArea('');
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        },

        isValidTag: function (tag) {
            return validator('validate-alphanum', tag);
        },

        OnBlurEvent: function (object) {
            if (this.valueArea() && this.valueArea().length > 0) {
                if (!this.correctValue(this.valueArea())) {
                    this.valueArea('');
                }
            }
        },

        deleteTag: function (self, value, event) {
            event ? event.stopPropagation() : false;
            var key = -1;
            _.each(this.list(), function (element, index) {
                if (value === element) {
                    key = index;
                }
            });
            if (key > -1) {
                this.list.splice(key, 1);
                this.joinList(this.list());
                this.valueArea('');
            }
        },

        joinList: function (array) {
            this.value(array.join(','));
        },

        hasTag: function (value) {
            return this.list().indexOf(value) !== -1;
        }
    });
});
```

the knockout template is on the way...

> StackOverflow/Catalog/view/base/web/template/form/element/tags.html

```
<div class="tags">
    <div class="admin__control-text">
        <div class="apps-share-chips-editor">
            <input class="admin__control-text" type="hidden"
                   data-bind="
        value: value,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled
    }"/>
            <span data-bind="foreach: { data: list, as: 'item' }">
                <span class="field-tag-chip">
                <div class="field-tag-content" data-bind="text: item"></div>
                <div class="field-tag-close-before">
                    <span class="field-tag-close" data-bind="event: {click: $parent.deleteTag.bind($parent, $index)}"></span>
                </div>
                </span>
            </span>
            <textarea
                    class="field-tag-input" placeholder="Add more tags..." data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges, blur: OnBlurEvent},
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        value: valueArea
        "></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

some styling maybe?...

> StackOverflow/Catalog/view/base/web/css/tags.css

```
.field-tag-content {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.field-tag-chip {
    background: #e0e0e0;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    color: #444;
    margin: 4px 1px 0 2px;
    outline: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:5px;
    padding-right:25px;
}

.field-tag-input {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 4px 0 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    height: 25px;
    outline: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    resize: none;
    width:50%;
}
.field-tag-close-before {
    position:relative;
}
.field-tag-close{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.field-tag-close:before,
.field-tag-close:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #303030;
}

.field-tag-close:before {
    webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.field-tag-close:after {
    webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Why put everything in the `view/base`? I don't have a clear answer for it, but it seems right for me because Magento team is placing all their UI elements in the `view/base` as well? :)

And finally, you will need to add your `tags.css` to the `view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml` and the `view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xml`.

So that it's it! Now your input should look like this:

[image: ui-element-tags]

Cheers.