# How to hide upload file field using jquery in magento2

Tags: magento2, ui

I want to hide upload file filed using jquery in magento2

```
    <field name="type">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Ktpl\BannerManagement\Model\Config\Source\Type</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Type</item>
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">type</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Ktpl_BannerManagement/js/form/element/element</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
      <field name="default_image">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Ktpl_BannerManagement/form/element/defaultTemplate</item>
                        <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">bannerdefaultimageClass</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
```

code in js:

```
     var field4 = jQuery('body').find(".bannerimageClass");

        if (value == 1) {
            field4.hide();
        } else {
            field4.show();
        }
```

but it not working

Comment: accept if helpful !!!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in `setInterval()`, your code run before element was build

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  var field4 = jQuery('body').find(".bannerimageClass");

        if (value == 1) {
            field4.hide();
        } else {
            field4.show();
        }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JS should be like this.

> Ktpl_BannerManagement/js/form/element/element

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',      
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($,_, uiRegistry, text, modal) {
    'use strict';
    return select.extend({      

        initialize: function (){
            this.showHideField();
        },
        showHideField: function(){
            selectValue = $('input[name="type"]').val();
            if(selectValue == 'yes') {
                //Do stuff with your code
            }
        }, 
    });
});
```

Take refrance [From here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157575/magento-2-1-ui-component-hide-and-show-field-base-on-dropdown-field)

I hope it helps!